# Parent and child web components sharing the same attribute

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I'm trying to create a custom textfield web component based on Material Web Components *mwc-textfield*:

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit-element';
import '@material/mwc-textfield';

export class CustomTextfield extends LitElement {

    static get properties() {
        return {
            label: {type: String},
            required: {type: Boolean},
            value: {type: String}
        }
    };

    get value_() {
        return this.shadowRoot.getElementById("input").value;
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.label = "";
        this.value = "";
        this.required = false;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <mwc-textfield id="input"
                label="${this.label}"
                value="${(this.value === undefined) ? "" : this.value}"
                ?required="${this.required}"
                outlined
            >
            </mwc-textfield>
        `;
    };
}

customElements.define('custom-textfield', CustomTextfield);
```

At this moment, I can get the mwc-textfield *value* attribute with the custom-textfield *value_* attribute. Is there any way to get the mwc-textfield *value* attribute with the custom-textfield *value* attribute?

Comment: Maybe try `value = element.getAttribute('value');`?

Answer (score 1):

For that to happen the value attribute in mwc-textfield should be [reflecting](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#property-options) its value, but that's not what's happening in https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/packages/textfield/src/mwc-textfield-base.ts#L123

So, at the moment it's not possible what you are looking for.

But anyway check this [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/issues/289) where they talk about the possible future which is implementing an internal api to mimic form elements with [Form Associated Custom Elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-face-example)